# Error in TF variable singleton variable creation in updating dynamic model

Tags: python, tensorflow

Following the papers Progressive Gans (https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10196), I implement keras.Model that needs to grow in size (layers). I first initialize the full model. But when the time making an inference, I will use only partial of model but the same trainable_variables, e.g. 4x4 then 8x8. So that the trainable_variables passing to train_step which decorated with tf.function will be different. This work properly for computing gradient etc. but not optimizer.apply_gradients.

The code look something like this:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
G = Generator()
with strategy.scope():
    Opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
    G.initialize_model() # initialize full model

@tf.function
def train_step(optimizer, model, var_to_train):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        Loss = loss(model(datasets))
    grads = tape.gradient(Loss, variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, variables)) # this will raise ValueError

res = 4 # resolution of 4x4
for ep in range(epochs):
    if ep % 100 == 0:
        res = res * 2
        cur_model = G.forward(output_shape=(res, res, 3)) # output for given image resolution
    
    var = cur_model.trainable_variables # this variables will be increasing as we grow model

    strategy.run(train_step, args=(Opt, cur_model, var))
```

Note, however, that this will work fine when train_step is not used in the context of tf.function or in MirroredStrategy. From last section of seem not to solve the problem. I tried tf.distribute.ReplicaContext.all_reduce or any equivalent method for obtaining local results from all replica but it won't work since the trainable_variables are created inside the strategy.scope() so every update must be in the context of Replica.

The only naive solution I could is to train, for example 4x4 model and save it. Then use transfer learning load it back to 8x8 model.
I want to use usual keras optimizer which support any dynamic trainable_variables passed through tf.function context.

[1]: [https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables:~:text=shape%3D()%2C%20dtype%3Dfloat32](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables:%7E:text=shape%3D()%2C%20dtype%3Dfloat32))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First call `optimizer._create_all_weights(var)` where the argument var is the full model. This will make the optimizer create all variables and must be done at the beginning before making any updates. In updating gradient it won't create again but still can provide a subset of it. This work in the context of tf.function too.